# Como crear un Arrays en php usando JSON

Tags: php

Cordial Saludo a todo el grupo de Stackoverflow, soy nuevo programando y tengo la siguiente consulta: quiero convertir este archivo php para que me muestre un array con todos los datos consignados en las variables ndom, fdom, dbru, subt1, desc21, subt2, desc5, subt3, desc2, subt4, desc1, subt5, tdesc, dneto. Intenté modificando en la consulta el INSERT por SELECT y lo que hace es mostrarme los campos vacíos quisiera utilizar json para hacer este array ya que posteriormente pienso utilizarlo para hacerle un llamado desde una app. De antemano gracias por su colaboración. El códgio que tengo hasta ahora es este:

```
<?php

$json=array();
    if(isset($_GET["nd"]) && ($_GET["fd"]) &&($_GET["db"]) && ($_GET["sb1"]) && ($_GET["d1"]) && ($_GET["sb2"]) && ($_GET["d2"]) && ($_GET["sb3"]) && ($_GET["d3"]) && ($_GET["sb4"]) && ($_GET["d4"]) && ($_GET["sb5"]) && ($_GET["td"]) && isset($_GET["dn"])){
        $nd = $_GET['nd'];
        $fd = $_GET['fd'];
        $db = $_GET['db'];
        $sb1 = $_GET['sb1'];
        $d1 = $_GET['d1'];
        $sb2 = $_GET['sb2'];
        $d2 = $_GET['d2'];
        $sb3 = $_GET['sb3'];
        $d3 = $_GET['d3'];
        $sb4 = $_GET['sb4'];
        $d4 = $_GET['d4'];
        $sb5 = $_GET['sb5'];
        $td = $_GET['td'];
        $dn = $_GET['dn'];

$conexion = mysqli_connect 
("tulocalhost","tu bd","tu contraseña","tu tabla" ) or die  
("Sin Conexion");

        $consulta="INSERT INTO diezmos(ndom, fdom, dbru, subt1,  
desc21, subt2, desc5, subt3, desc2, subt4, desc1, subt5, tdesc, dneto) 

VALUES  
('{$nd}','{$fd}','{$db}','{$sb1}','{$d1}','{$sb2}','{$d2}','{$sb3}','{$d3}','{$sb4}','{$d4}','{$sb5}','{$td}','{$dn}')";
        $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);


        if($consulta){
           $consulta="SELECT * FROM diezmos  WHERE 

ndom='{$nd}'";
           $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);

            if($reg=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
                $json['datos'][]=$reg;
            }
            mysqli_close($conexion);
            echo json_encode($json);
        }



        else{
            $results['nd']='';
            $results['fd']='';
            $results['db']='';
            $results['sb1']='';
            $results['d1']='';
            $results['sb2']='';
            $results['d2']='';
            $results['sb3']='';
            $results['d3']='';
            $results['sb4']='';
            $results['d4']='';
            $results['sb5']='';
            $results['td']='';
            $results['dn']='';
            $json['datos'][]=$results;
            echo json_encode($json);
        }

    }
    else{   
            $results['nd']='';
            $results['fd']='';
            $results['db']='';
            $results['sb1']='';
            $results['d1']='';
            $results['sb2']='';
            $results['d2']='';
            $results['sb3']='';
            $results['d3']='';
            $results['sb4']='';
            $results['d4']='';
            $results['sb5']='';
            $results['td']='';
            $results['dn']='';
            $json['datos'][]=$results;
            echo json_encode($json);
        }
?>
```

Comment: Es decir, necesitas pasar tu Json a un array legible de PHP?

Comment: El resultado que busco es que me muestre los datos de la bd externa que tengo en phpmyadmin sin embargo a recorrer la consulta me muestra los campos vacíos: `{"datos":]{"fd":"","db":"","sb1":"","d1":"","sb2":"","d2":"","sb3":"","d3":"","sb4":"","d4":"","sb5":"","td":"","dn":""}]}` y lo que busco es que me muestre los datos consignados en cada una de las variables.